# Como puedo pasar los datos del Combobox a la jList "Asignatura"

Tags: netbeans

Solo quiero saber que debo poner para que los datos del combobox se pasen a la lista de "Asignaturas"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo como observaran en la siguiente imagen, donde esta la flecha es el error, ya que creo que no es para el combobox, pero en este caso que debo cambiar para que lea el dato del combobox? o lo dejo asi nomas si es que esta bien.

Se que las imagenes no son bien recibidas cuando no hay un codigo, pero solo quiero saber que es lo que debo cambiar para que los datos del combobox puedan ser colocados en su lista correpondiente, y si hace falta mas informacion, me pueden avisar.

jListAsignaturas.setModel(LAsignatura); //Eso es lo unico que quiero cambiar para que lea los datos del combobox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la tercera imagen estara bien "LAsignatura.addElement(asignatura);" para que el dato del combobox pase en su lista correspondiente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya intentaste con casting?

Comment: gracias bro, ya lo coloque bien y me sale